# Google Indexing API

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-indexing-api

I have a job portal website (Wordpress + PHP) and I want using Google Indexing API for my website. I don't have any experience on GoogleAPI so I just read their guidance.
According to the guide, to use the Indexing API it has 3 steps:

> 1. Complete the prerequisites by enabling the Indexing API, creating a new service account, and verifying ownership in Search Console.
> 2. Get an access token to authenticate your API call.
> 3. Send requests to notify Google of new, updated, or deleted web pages.

I completed the step 1 but step 2 and 3 it really confuse me. Seem like I need obtain the OAuth token with coding but where do I put these code ? For using API, they show me this example :

```
POST https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish
{
  "url": "https://careers.google.com/jobs/google/technical-writer",
  "type": "URL_UPDATED"
}
```

Again, Im not sure where do I put these block code to using API. Can anyone know about this can explain step by step how to do it for me? Last question : because my website get around 10 - 15 new job post per day. Can I somehow set this Indexing API automatic send request to Google whenever someone post a new job ?
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate Google Indexing API: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/indexing.googleapis.com

In PHP you find more Information about the Error with:

```
$body = $response->getBody();
$stringBody = (string) $body;
```

Comment: this solution is so simple and yet nowhere else documented thanks for this

Answer (score 4):

You should be passing it as a Bearer authentication Header in your request.

> Authorization: Bearer

You may also be able to pass it as part as a request string I cant remember if this works with post calls though.

```
POST https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish?Access_token=XXXX
{
  "url": "https://careers.google.com/jobs/google/technical-writer",
  "type": "URL_UPDATED"
}
```

If you are using php you should consider using the [Google php client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) which will handle most of this for you.  which is what they recommend in the example [here](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/get-token)

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

// service_account_file.json is the private key that you created for your service account.
$client->setAuthConfig('service_account_file.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');

// Get a Guzzle HTTP Client
$httpClient = $client-&gt;authorize();
$endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';

// Define contents here. The structure of the content is described in the next step.
$content = "{
  \"url\": \"http://example.com/jobs/42\",
  \"type\": \"URL_UPDATED"
}";

$response = $httpClient->post($endpoint, [ 'body' => $content ]);
$status_code = $response->getStatusCode();
```

Make sure you have set up the service account properly [create service account](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/prereqs#create-service-account)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't know where to put these code. Do I need to make a new file and place it on server or installs a plugin and put these code on my website Header ?

Comment: Yes a php script is going to have to be on a file on your server.   The call itself must be authenticated.  This is programming its not something that you can just place on your website and run it.  Your going to have to look up how to send an authenticated HTTP Post with php or use the client library that google recommends.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this as I'm in the same boat, sort-of. I'm planning on adding some code to functions.php using the WordPress "save_post" hook to trigger this once a job has been created/saved/updated (and a mix of ACF fields to only trigger if it's actually a job post).

Comment: $client-&gt;authorize();  should be $client->authorize();
and
\"type\": \"URL_UPDATED"  should be  \"type\": \"URL_UPDATED\"

Answer (score 1):

You must sure verify site ownership in Search Console : https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home

1. Click your verified property.
2. Select Verification details from the Settings gear next to your verified property.
3. Under Verified owners, click Add an owner.
4. Add your service account email address as an owner to the property.

You can confirm your service account like 
my-service-account@project-name.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is just to install the Rankmath Indexing API plugin. After adding the owner as Ruha Thai explain above - upload the JSON code to the plugin settings and that's it.

Comment: Hi, the original question is focused on Google API. So, when answering, it's better to keep in mind author's  intent

Answer (score -2):

Rank Math just released free Indexing plugin for WordPress, you can give it a try, it does all the things automatically. More details: https://rankmath.com/blog/google-indexing-api/